# Virtualbox - No suitable module for running kernel found

Tags: ubuntu, server, virtualbox

I just installed on Ubuntu server Virtualbox. Virtual box told me that I have to install virtualbox-dkms and linux-headers-generic, what I did so. But there is stil error

- No suitable module for running kernel found [fail] when I want to start virtualbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me on Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.3 was :

```
apt-get install linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic linux-signed-generic

sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
```

Comment: Had to remove "linux-signed-generic", otherwise this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had troubles with this for many hours! 
Here is what worked for me:

I'm running on version 14.04 LTS ubuntu.

**First:** make sure you remove your virtualbox so that we can fresh install.

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
```

**Second:** you need to install virtualbox but not through the command line. 
   Go Here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3 and download the one that says:

> Ubuntu 13.04 ("Raring Ringtail") / 13.10 ("Saucy Salamander") /
>   14.04 ("Trusty Tahr") / 14.10 ("Utopic Unicorn")  i386 |  **AMD64**

download either i386 or AMD64

**Third:** open the package you just downloaded. This should open in **Ubuntu Software Center**

**Fourth:** Click Install. This will install all virtualbox-dkms, linux-headers etc.

This should hopefully have done it.

- I needed this to install vagrant next and worked just fine!

Answer (score 1):

My configuration:

> Linux Mint 17 (Trusty 14.04 Amd64)
>
> Kernel: 4.4.0-34-generic

1 - Purge old installation (don't worry: existing virtual machines will remain intact):

`apt-get purge virtualbox`

2 - Find and comment out (or remove) VBox repository from apt source files:

`grep -r 'virtualbox' /etc/apt/*`

3 - Update:

`apt-get update`

4 - Install linux headers according to your kernel:

`` apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` ``

5 - Download VBox .deb file at https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads (in my case: trusty_amd64)

`wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.2/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.2-108956~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb`

6 - Install the download package:

`dpkg -i ./virtualbox-5.1_5.1.2-108956~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb`

If any error, check logs: `tail /var/log/vbox-install.log`